# Healthkit not returning latest data on iphone. Using healthkit between iPhone and Apple watch

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-watch, healthkit

I am creating an app that provides workout information. On apple watch i have three labels that actively shows HEARTRATE ,DISTANCE TRAVELLED and CALORIES BURNED. Things work fine with apple watch, however the area where things go bad is when i try to show this data on iphone in realtime.

**APPLE WATCH PART :-**

I started workout on apple watch and saved it using folling code

```
 func startWorkoutSession() {
    // Start a workout session with the configuration
    if let workoutConfiguration = configuration {
        do {
            workoutSession = try HKWorkoutSession(configuration: workoutConfiguration)
            workoutSession?.delegate = self
            workoutStartDate = Date()

            healthStore.start(workoutSession!)

        } catch {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Then i save that workout on apple watch using following code :-

```
 func saveWorkout() {
    // Create and save a workout sample
    let configuration = workoutSession!.workoutConfiguration
    let isIndoor = (configuration.locationType == .indoor) as NSNumber
    print("locationType: \(configuration)")

    let workout = HKWorkout(activityType: configuration.activityType,
                            start: workoutStartDate ?? Date(),
                            end: workoutEndDate ?? Date(),
                            workoutEvents: workoutEvents,
                            totalEnergyBurned: totalEnergyBurned,
                            totalDistance: totalDistance,
                            metadata: [HKMetadataKeyIndoorWorkout:isIndoor]);

    healthStore.save(workout) { success, _ in
        if success {
            self.addSamples(toWorkout: workout)
        }
    }

    // Pass the workout to Summary Interface Controller
    // WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllers(withNames: ["StopPauseInterfaceController"], contexts: [workout])


    if #available(watchOSApplicationExtension 4.0, *){
        // Create the route, save it, and associate it with the provided workout.
        routeBuilder?.finishRoute(with: workout, metadata: metadata) { (newRoute, error) in

            guard newRoute != nil else {
                // Handle the error here...
                return
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        // fallback to earlier versions
    }
}
```

Then i added samples to those workouts using following code :-

```
 func addSamples(toWorkout workout: HKWorkout) {
    // Create energy and distance samples
    let totalEnergyBurnedSample = HKQuantitySample(type: HKQuantityType.activeEnergyBurned(),
                                                   quantity: totalEnergyBurned,
                                                   start: workoutStartDate!,
                                                   end: workoutEndDate ?? Date())

    let totalDistanceSample = HKQuantitySample(type: HKQuantityType.distanceWalkingRunning(),
                                               quantity: totalDistance,
                                               start: workoutStartDate!,
                                               end: workoutEndDate ?? Date())

    // Add samples to workout
    healthStore.add([totalEnergyBurnedSample, totalDistanceSample], to: workout) { (success: Bool, error: Error?) in
        if success {
            // Samples have been added
        }
    }
}
```

**IPHONE PART :-**

This is where things get worse. I try to access the healthkit store using HKSampleObjectQuery and It just returns static values. P.S - I am fetching healthkit store every one second for latest data using NSTimer.

The code which is called every second is :-

```
func extractDataFromHealthStore(identifier : HKQuantityTypeIdentifier,completion: @escaping (String) -> ()) {


    let heightType = HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier:identifier)!
    let distantPastDate = Date.distantPast
    let endDate = Date()

    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: distantPastDate, end: endDate, options: .strictStartDate)

    // Get the single most recent Value
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate, ascending: true)


    let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: heightType, predicate: predicate, limit: 1, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { (query, results, error) in
        if let result = results?.first as? HKQuantitySample{
            print("Height => \(result.quantity)")

            completion("\(result.quantity)")

        }else{
            print("OOPS didnt get height \nResults => \(String(describing: results)), error => \(error)")
             completion("")
        }
    }
    self.healthStore.execute(query)
}
```

Please guide Me if my whole approach is wrong, or if it is right then what is the mistake at my end.